# Novice python user need help passing data between functions

Tags: python, function

I am finishing an assignment for a class where a teacher can input the student ID numbers and the students grades. The final grade will be calculated and returned next to the students number. I can calculate the final grade just fine, but I cannot append the grade to the list of student numbers.

```
def assignments():
    assign1 = int(input("Assignment 1 grade: "))
    if assign1 > 100:
        print ("Please input a valid grade value.")
        assign1 = int(input("Assignment 1 grade: "))
    assign2 = int(input("Assignment 2 grade: "))
    if assign2 > 100:
        print ("Please input a valid grade value.")
        assign2 = int(input("Assignment 2 grade: "))
    assign3 = int(input("Assignment 3 grade: "))
    if assign3 > 100:
        print ("Please input a valid grade value.")
        assign3 = int(input("Assignment 3 grade: "))
    assign4 = int(input("Assignment 4 grade: "))
    if assign4 > 100:
        print ("Please input a valid grade value.")
        assign4 = int(input("Assignment 4 grade: "))
    assign5 = int(input("Assignment 5 grade: "))
    if assign5 > 100:
        print ("Please input a valid grade value.")
        assign5 = int(input("Assignment 5 grade: "))
    assign6 = int(input("Assignment 6 grade: "))
    if assign6 > 100:
        print ("Please input a valid grade value.")
        assign6 = int(input("Assignment 6 grade: "))
    assign7 = int(input("Assignment 7 grade: "))
    if assign7 > 100:
        print ("Please input a valid grade value.")
        assign7 = int(input("Assignment 7 grade: "))
    assign8 = int(input("Assignment 8 grade: "))
    if assign8 > 100:
        print ("Please input a valid grade value.")
        assign8 = int(input("Assignment 8 grade: "))
    assign9 = int(input("Assignment 9 grade: "))
    if assign9 > 100:
        print ("Please input a valid grade value.")
        assign9 = int(input("Assignment 9 grade: "))
    assign10 = int(input("Assignment 10 grade: "))
    if assign10 > 100:
        print ("Please input a valid grade value.")
        assign10 = int(input("Assignment 10 grade: "))
    assignGrade = assign1 + assign2 + assign3 + assign4 + assign5 + assign6 + assign7 + assign8 + assign9 + assign10
    aGrade = assignGrade / 10
    print("The final grade for all assignments is: ")
    print(aGrade)
    midterm = int(input("Midterm grade: "))
    if midterm > 100:
        print ("Please input a valid grade value.")
        midterm = int(input("Midterm grade: "))
    finalExam = int(input("Final Exam grade: "))
    if finalExam > 100:
        print ("Please input a valid grade value.")
        finalExam = int(input("Final Exam grade: "))
    testsGrade = midterm + finalExam
    tGrade = testsGrade / 2
    print("The final grade for all test is: ")
    print(tGrade)
    participation = int(input("Participation grade: "))
    if participation > 100:
        print ("Please input a valid grade value.")
        participation = int(input("Participation grade: "))
    partGrade = participation
    print("The final grade for Participation is: ")
    print(partGrade)
    finalGrade = aGrade + tGrade + partGrade / 3


def students():
    netIDList = [] 
    maxLengthList = 6 
    while len(netIDList) < maxLengthList:
        ID = input("Enter Student's Net ID: ")
        netIDList.append(ID)
    for s in netIDList:
        print("Please input grades for student " + s)
        assignments()
        f = assignments().finalGrade
        netIDList.append(": " + f)
    print(netIDList)

def main():
    students()

main()
```

Comment: Using `return <value>` will return a value back to the called, basic OOP

Comment: identation is wrong, please fix so that you have a working program

Comment: The indentation is correct in my IDLE environment, so ignore that part of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
f = assignments().finalGrade
netIDList.append(": " + f)
```

You're accessing `assignments` like it is an object rather than a function.  You want to have `assignments` return a value to append.

```
def assignments():
   # do all your input and calculation here
   finalGrade = aGrade + tGrade + partGrade / 3
   return finalGrade
```

This way, the function will send this value back to the place where it was called from.  Then, change

```
f = assignments().finalGrade
```

to

```
f = assignments()
```

***EDIT:*** Your for loop should look basically like this:

```
for s in netIDList:
        print("Please input grades for student " + s)
        f = assignments()
        netIDList.append(": " + f)
```

but this will result in a somewhat confusing list:

```
[student1_name, student2_name, student1_score, student2_score]
```

So I would use a dictionary:

```
student_score_map = {}
for s in netIDList:
            print("Please input grades for student " + s)
            f = assignments()
            student_score_map[s] = f
```

This way you can print all student names *with their score* like so:

```
for s in netIDList:
    print(s + ' final score:' + student_score_map[s])
```

Comment: Thank you! that answered that part. Now if I can only get my for each loop to work properly.

Comment: @BryanHaoui   Edited, I think I got what you meant here, if not open up a new question with whatever is going wrong.  GLHF

Comment: No need, thank you for all of your help. The code worked exactly the way I wanted it to.